# Interpreting Mathematical notations

Tags: real-analysis

How should the notation 
$$L:= \{x\in \mathbb{R}:x\text{ is a lower bound of }S\}$$
be interpreted as?

Comment: $L$ is the collection of all real numbers $x$ such that $x\leqslant y$ for every $y\in S$.

Comment: Does this follows necessarily that L is a subset of R?

Comment: Since it is a set of real numbers, by definition it is a subset of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

It means that $L$ is a set containing all the Real Number lower bound for $S$.

NotE: Recall the definition of lowerbound.